# Pairs with Specific Difference python

Tags: python, interview-questions

> Given an array arr of distinct integers
>   and a nonnegative integer `k`, write a function
>   findPairsWithGivenDifference that returns an array of all pairs `[x,y]`
>   in arr, such that `x - y = k`. If no such pairs exist, return an empty
>   array.
>
> In your solution, try to reduce the memory usage while maintaining
>   time efficiency. Prove the correctness of your solution and analyze
>   its time and space complexities.
>
> Note: the order of the pairs in the output array should maintain the
>   order of the y element in the original array.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> input:  `arr = [0, -1, -2, 2, 1], k = 1 output: [[1, 0], [0, -1], [-1,
>   -2], [2, 1]]`
>
> input:  `arr = [1, 7, 5, 3, 32, 17, 12], k = 17`
>
> output: []
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> [time limit] 5000ms
>
> [input] array.integer arr
>
> 0 ≤ arr.length ≤ 100 [input]integer k
>
> k ≥ 0 [output] array.array.integer

```
def find_pairs_with_given_difference(arr, k):
    numbers = set()
    output = []
    # insert arr element into set
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        numbers.add(arr[i])

    # loop through the entire array
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        difference = arr[i]
        if difference - k in numbers:
            output.append([difference,(difference - k)])
    return output

Test case #1
Input: [4,1], 3
Expected: [[4,1]]
Actual: [[4, 1]]


Test Case #2
Input: [1,5,11,7], 4
Expected: [[5,1],[11,7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the post (and in [WolframH's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189700/11728)) has a bug:

```
>>> find_pairs_with_given_difference([1], 0)
[[1, 1]]
```

There is no pair of items `[1, 1]` in the input array.

Answer (score 1):

If the array were longer, I word first sort it to a list of tuples `(item, original_position)`, and then for each element, start iterating forwards, until the threshold `k` is passed

```
sorted_items = [(item, pos) for pos, item in sorted(enumerate(arr), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

> ```
> [(-2, 2), (-1, 1), (0, 0), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
> ```

```
def find_pairs(sorted_items):
    for i, (y, pos) in enumerate(sorted_items):
        for x, pos2 in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] - y <= k, sorted_items[i+1:]):
            if x - y == k:
                yield pos, [x, y]
```

> ```
> [(2, [-1, -2]), (1, [0, -1]), (0, [1, 0]), (4, [2, 1])]
> ```

```
list(pair for _, pair in sorted(find_pairs(sorted_items)))
```

> ```
> [[1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, -2], [2, 1]]
> ```

This way you eliminate the quadratic growth of the iterations

Comment: i made my algorithm use the `x` and `y` variable names of the question to make it more clear. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

The set `numbers` can be created directly from an iterable, in this case

```
numbers = set(arr)
```

You should iterate over the items of `arr`, not indices:

```
for y in arr:
    if y - k in numbers:
        output.append([y, y - k])
```

Or use a list comprehension, which is more or less made for things like this:

```
output = [[y, y - k] for y in arr if y - k in numbers]
```

Put everything together and your function becomes very short and readable:

```
def find_pairs_with_given_difference(arr, k):
    numbers = set(arr)
    return [[y, y - k] for y in arr if y - k in numbers]
```

Comment: This produces the output in the wrong order. The problem description says that `find_pairs_with_given_difference([0, -1, -2, 2, 1], 1)` should return `[[1, 0], [0, -1], [-1, -2], [2, 1]]`, but the code in this answer returns `[[0, -1], [-1, -2], [2, 1], [1, 0]]`.

Comment: this can be fixed to `return [[y + k, y] for y in arr if y + k in numbers]`